# Codeblock and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks

I got Codeblock 12.11.
I compiled OpenGL project (and empty with linked OpenGL) and I can see my OpenGL is 4.3, it's fine.
But wait, something weird is here, I used glBegin, glEnd and also glVertex what were deleted in older version, then anybody can tell me how it works?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Please edit the question for clarity

Comment: You can use the deprecated legacy functions as long as you use the *Compatibility Profile*. You have to enable the *Core Profile* to make the old function unusable.

Comment: how can I disable _Compatibility Profile_?

Comment: @JohnSmith read datenwolfs answer. You need to request a context with a `core profile`. You can either do it directly with `wgl` and `glx` or you can use platform independent frameworks like `GLUT`, `GLFW` and many others. I mean, you could just use whatever you are using now, just search for how to create a OpenGL context with a core profile with whatever library or API you are currently using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't ask specifically for a OpenGL-4 core context you will get a backward compatible context which also supports all deprecated features. If you use the "old way" of creating an OpenGL context you will automatically get a compatibility profile. To actually get a core profile (possibly even forward compatible) you must use the (relatively new) `...CreateContextAttribs` method.

WGL variant: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt

GLX variant: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/glx_create_context.txt